# How to use (\u) with Variable in Java

Tags: java, android

Can I use \u with Stored Value in a variable ?

I want to awesome icon in android

when I pass a static value to textview like this
textView.setText('\uf13b'); i will get awesome icon

but when I want to restore the string from database like this  (\uf13b) or (f13b) I will get it as a string!

how can I convert it to character

[image]

**If I store (\uf13b) as a string in database I will get it as a string**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have F13B in a String, you can transform it into the equivalent Unicode character with:

```
char awesomeChar = (char) Integer.parseInt("f13b", 16)
```

Output is 

Note that this is a [private use area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) character and you need to use a  special icon font to see the icon you expect.